# Lambda function behavior in multiuser environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud

I have a requirement to run a Python script continuously for 24 hours for a particular user. I am planning to create an AWS lambda function for python code and execute it based on an API trigger. How will AWS lambda behave when there are multiple API calls were made to execute the python script for n no of users? Any suggestion will help. I am new to AWS and AWS Lambda

I have created a Lambda function to execute the Python script.

Comment: An AWS Lambda function can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes. If you want the script to run for 24 hours, then you should use something else (eg an Amazon EC2 instance) to run your code.